# If $f'(x)=f'(y)$ for all $x,y$ in $(0,1)$, then f is linear function.

Tags: real-analysis

Please, is this statement true? Why?

> If $f'(x)=f'(y)$ $\forall x,y \in (0,1)$, then $f$ is  a linear function.

Comment: for all x,y in (0,1)

Comment: A linear function.... on $(0,1)$ or everywhere? What is a linear function to you? Linear in the sense of a linear transformation or in the sense that its graph is a line?

Comment: I mean a linear function f(x)=ax+b, where a,b are constants

Comment: But let's say $f(x)=x^2$ on $x<=0$, $f(x)=x$ on $0<x<1$, $f(x)=x^2$ on $1<=x$, is clearly not a function of the form $f(x)=ax+b$, but it does satisfy your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
 If $f'(x)=f'(y)$ for all $x,y\in(0,1)$, then that means that $f'$ is a constant, i.e. $f'(x)=m$ in $(0,1).$ Can you find $f(x)$ using that equation?

Comment: Yes, I can. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user160329 You're welcome! Glad I could help! $\overset{\cdot\cdot}\smile$

Answer (score 0):

If $f'(x)=f'(y)$ in $(0,1)$, then $f'(x)=K$ ; for $K$ a constant, so that $f= \int f'(x)dx=...$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $C$ be a common value of $f'(x)$ on $(0,1)$, so $f'(x)=C$ for all $x \in (0,1)$ and $f(x)=Cx+D$, where $D$- constant.